# Methods unavailable for System.Threading.ThreadPool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, threadpool

Looking at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.110).aspx I see they are using `System.Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. For some reason I only have three methods available for `ThreadPool`. I have `System.Threading` as a reference and I'm `using` everything they have in the example I linked.

What would cause this method to be unavailable?

[image]

Comment: What platform are you targetting?

Comment: I'm creating a portable class library for Xamarin iOS and Android. The Target Frameworks in the properties are .NET Framework 4.5, Silverlight 5, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.iOS (Classic). Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Silverlight selects the .NETCore subset.  Nice for the user, quick download when visiting a web page.  Not so nice if you expect features.

Comment: I created a new project that doesn't target Silverlight 5 to test. It seems Silverlight 5 is preventing me from using that method. Xamarin seems to require Silverlight 5. Is there a way around this?